# POSTGRESQL Recursive LEFT JOIN on Array

Tags: postgresql, recursion

I have the following table with the parent_path array:

```
Id   | Account Name | parent_path
1      A              {1}
2      B              {2,1}
3      C              {3,2,1}
4      D              {4,3,2,1}
```

What I'm looking to do is to have a recursive left join in order to create 1 column per item in the parent_path array

```
Id   | Account Name | parent_path | parent_name1 | parent_name2 | parent_name3
1      A              NULL          NULL           NULL           NULL
2      B              {1}           A              NULL           NULL  
3      C              {2,1}         B              A              NULL
4      D              {3,2,1}       C              B              A
```

Thanks!

Comment: The resulting table cannot depend on data (like in your case). Postgresql does not support this AFAIK. Unless you know a priori the max number of columns. Still, what a waste of space.

Comment: As said, you can't have a dynamic number of columns in postgresql. You could create a single column containing the parent names in an array (basically a `map(id -> account_name)` on the parent_path array), or limit the number of `parent_name_x` columns.

Comment: @Marth if I know there's a maximum of 8 items in the parent_path, how would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a cleaner solution, using PostgreSQL [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/intarray.html), instead. It works best for small(ish) tables, since it's not optimised for performance:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;

SELECT id,
       name,
       path - id as parents,
       (SELECT name FROM hierarchy h2 WHERE h2.id = (h.path - h.id)[1]) as parent_1,
       (SELECT name FROM hierarchy h2 WHERE h2.id = (h.path - h.id)[2]) as parent_2,
       (SELECT name FROM hierarchy h2 WHERE h2.id = (h.path - h.id)[3]) as parent_3,
       (SELECT name FROM hierarchy h2 WHERE h2.id = (h.path - h.id)[4]) as parent_4,
       (SELECT name FROM hierarchy h2 WHERE h2.id = (h.path - h.id)[5]) as parent_5,
       (SELECT name FROM hierarchy h2 WHERE h2.id = (h.path - h.id)[6]) as parent_6,
       (SELECT name FROM hierarchy h2 WHERE h2.id = (h.path - h.id)[7]) as parent_7
FROM hierarchy h
```

In my code, it produced the following (truncated) output:

```
+--+-----------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|id|name       |parents|parent_1|parent_2|parent_3|
+--+-----------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|1 |Europe     |       |NULL    |NULL    |NULL    |
|2 |Germany    |{1}    |Europe  |NULL    |NULL    |
|4 |Netherlands|{1}    |Europe  |NULL    |NULL    |
|7 |Africa     |       |NULL    |NULL    |NULL    |
|10|France     |{1}    |Europe  |NULL    |NULL    |
|12|America    |       |NULL    |NULL    |NULL    |
|17|Finland    |{1}    |Europe  |NULL    |NULL    |
|3 |Berlin     |{1,2}  |Europe  |Germany |NULL    |
+--+-----------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an abuse of SQL, but here goes:

```
 with get_names as (
  select h.id, h.account_name, h.parent_path, array_agg(h2.account_name order by p.rn) as name_path
    from hier h
         cross join lateral unnest(h.parent_path) with ordinality as p(path_id, rn)
         join hier h2 on h2.id = p.path_id
   group by h.id, h.account_name, h.parent_path
)
select id, account_name, parent_path, 
       name_path[2] as parent_name1,
       name_path[3] as parent_name2,
       name_path[4] as parent_name3,
       name_path[5] as parent_name4,
       name_path[6] as parent_name5,
       name_path[7] as parent_name6,
       name_path[8] as parent_name7,
       name_path[9] as parent_name8
  from get_names;

 id | account_name | parent_path | parent_name1 | parent_name2 | parent_name3 | parent_name4 | parent_name5 | parent_name6 | parent_name7 | parent_name8 
----+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------
  1 | A            | {1}         |              |              |              |              |              |              |              | 
  2 | B            | {2,1}       | A            |              |              |              |              |              |              | 
  3 | C            | {3,2,1}     | B            | A            |              |              |              |              |              | 
  4 | D            | {4,3,2,1}   | C            | B            | A            |              |              |              |              | 
(4 rows)
```